# Adding Banner To Magento Product Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hi Everyone i am seek your expertise. I am working on a magento store and am wanting to add a banner to my product page like the image attached. This banner needs to be different on each product page so am wanting a way that i can either browse my computer for the image or add a url to the image location. I am thinking i need to create an attribute and then under Admin > Catalog > Manager Product > Images list i will be able to pull in the banner just like adding a new image product. Is this the correct way of doing it and if so, how can i specify on my template where the banner will be added (i.e at the top of the page). I have tryed to find some code where i can add so it knows that when i have this attribute to put it in that location. Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Ali

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry without the actual code there is not much help you will get. But this is an idea you can use:

Yes your thinking it correctly. Although a more elegant way to do this would be by adding an option in the image grid as (banner). This will allow you to use the power of existing image processing and handling systems in magento. 
Once this is done; simply add the code in template file for product view page (I am not sure whether this is a enterprise or community version or you are using a theme. It's best to enable the developer debugger option to view the template file path).

In terms of adding this code this should be fairly simple. You just need to check any image has been flagged as "banner" or not. Then do some resize to fit in the page and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply create a one new attribute for a product using for banner image and you can use that attribute on product view page, and the banner will be display on product page according to each banner attribute value specify in the admin. This will be very simple in use.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. i found this code

<img style="margin: 0px 0px 20px" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'product_banner')?>" width="960" height="400" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />

but when i add this to view.phtml page it comes up with lots of errors. Is this the type of code that i need to add to the view.phtml page

thanks